# JSP/PrimeFaces Spring Boot Tomcat memory leak issue

Tags: spring, jsp, jsf, tomcat, primefaces

I use

```
Tomcat 8.0.26
jsf 2.2.12
primefaces 5.2
Spring Boot 1.2.6.RELEASE
Spring 4.2.1.RELEASE
```

I use `Reload` button in `Tomcat Web Application Manager` and after reload of my application(`domain-api`)have a following issue:

```
The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their
classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory
leak (use a profiler to confirm):
/domain-api
```

Also, via Java VisualVM I can see growth of `javax.faces.*` objects after "reload"

This is sampler memory snapshots comparison:

[image]

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Managed similar issue time ago, it has been solved by tunning the java garbage collector in the JAVA_OPTS:

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS  -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=35 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:SurvivorRatio=6"

Where:

-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly avoid the use of heuristic rules for the Garbage collector funcionallity.

-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction place when the CMS(Concurrent MArk Sweeper) will be activated.

-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy disabled sizing memory generations ( With this we can set the parameter -XX : SurvivorRatio = 6 ) .

-XX:SurvivorRatio=6 establish the eden survivor relation to 1:6, this will give more room to young objects.

To optimize the performance of garbage collector threads the following parameters were used:

-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled : reduce pauses between CMS.

-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8  sets the number of parallel threads of garbage collection in 8 (one for each server processor ) .

-XX:+UseParNewGC This collector parallelized unlike the original collection in multiple threads when you have multiple processors.

-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC It is the concurrent collector A garbage collection algorithm that tries to do most of the work of garbage collection in the background without stopping application threads while running.

In my case with these options the memory was released faster. The eden and old memories were cleaned faster , optimizing resource release.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't helping. Still have the same javax.faces.* memory leak

Comment: Should JSP/PrimeFaces be placed in Tomcat shared lib or they can be packaged in application war file?

Comment: anyway, I tried both variants.. the same results. The number of `javax.faces.*` is growing. Also, in the Tomcat memory leak message I can see the growth of number of applications - `The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their
classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory
leak (use a profiler to confirm):
/domain-api
/domain-api`